# React native Animated.ScrollView animation stops working after updating page title

Tags: react-native, animation, react-hooks

I have an animation to create a sticky header. I am using flashlist with horizontal scroll so I cant use stickyHeaderIndices. It all works fine until I try to update the header. I've tried memo, callback, moving the header component out. I can't seem to get keep the sticky animation after I set the title. Any suggestions would be great.

```
const AppointmentManager = () => { 
   const [headerDate, setheaderDate] = useState('test');

   const range = [0, 109];

   const translateY = scrollY.interpolate({
      inputRange:range, 
      outputRange:range, 
      extrapolateLeft: 'clamp'
   });

   const onPageChange = ({viewableItems}: {viewableItems: ViewToken[]}) => {
       const currentPage = viewableItems?.at(0)?.item as IWeekAppointment

        if(currentPage?.currentMonth){
           setheaderDate(currentPage.currentMonth)  <- breaks sticky header animation 
        }
    }


    const WeekTemplate = ({renderedWeekItem}: {renderedWeekItem:IWeekAppointment}) => {

        const headers = renderedWeekItem.header

        return (
           <>
              <Animated.View style={{zIndex: 999, transform: [{translateY}]}}>
                 <WeekHeader headers={headers} />
              </Animated.View>

              <View> <Text>body</Text> <View>
           </>
        )
    }


   const weekView = useMemo( () => 

      <FlashList 
        removeClippedSubviews={true}
        estimatedItemSize={weekdayWrapperWidth} 
        pagingEnabled horizontal data={list} 
        renderItem={({item}) => <WeekTemplate renderedWeekItem={item} /> }
        onViewableItemsChanged={onPageChange} 
      />, [] );

  return(
     <>
        <Text>{headerDate}</Tex>
        <Animated.ScrollView scrollEventThrottle={1} onScroll={onScroll}>
            {weekView}
        </Animated.ScrollView>
     </>
  )
}
```